# Spring Cloud Gateway with spring-boot-starter-web

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-cloud-gateway

I am creating gateway for Spring Boot microservices using Spring Cloud Gateway. Gateway is also responsible for JWT authorization using Spring Security.

```
public class JwtAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    ...

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        String header = request.getHeader(JwtProperties.HEADER_STRING);

        if (header == null || !header.startsWith(JwtProperties.TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        Authentication authentication = getUsernamePasswordAuthentication(request);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private Authentication getUsernamePasswordAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(JwtProperties.HEADER_STRING).replace(JwtProperties.TOKEN_PREFIX, "");

        DecodedJWT decodedJWT = JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC512(JwtProperties.SECRET.getBytes())).build().verify(token);
        String username = decodedJWT.getSubject();

        if (username != null) {
            UserPrincipal principal = (UserPrincipal) userPrincipalService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, principal.getAuthorities());
            return auth;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

This filter is registred in configure method like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    ...
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), userPrincipalService))
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
            ...
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
        
    }
...
}
```

As you can see, Spring Security is using HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain interfaces which belong to spring-boot-starter-web. But that is **main problem** beacause it's incompatible with spring cloud gateway.

```
Spring MVC found on classpath, which is incompatible with Spring Cloud Gateway at this time. Please remove spring-boot-starter-web dependency.
```

Is there any way to avoid this error or any different solution for implementing jwt authorization filter on gateway?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [Documentation of spring cloud gateway](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#gateway-starter) it is explicitely stated that this product runs on top of Netty and requires webflux, hence it's not compatible with spring MVC.

The filter that you use (`JwtAuthorizationFilter`) is something that belongs to the non-reactive world so you probably should rewrite it with spring security for web flux building blocks.

Disclaimer, I'm not a spring web flux / spring-security expert, but please consider checking  [This application](https://github.com/raphaelDL/spring-webflux-security-jwt/blob/master/src/main/java/io/rapha/spring/reactive/security/SecuredRestApplication.java) - it shows how to define JWT secured application with a reactive version of spring security.

So bottom line you should choose whether you want a reactive application or a traditional one and use the relevant technologies but you can't really mix them.